# Prometheus - calculate difference in "device traffic-rate" between `now` and `30 mins ago`

Tags: prometheus, grafana, monitoring, snmp

I am upgrading a switch/router firmware and I want to make sure this upgrade does not disrupt traffic going through the switch. So, I want to have the traffic-rate-PRE-upgrade and traffic-rate-POST-upgrade and compare these two values.
For example: IF there was 100Mpps traffic PRE-upgrade and only 0.5Mpps POST-upgrade, I'll flag this as a potential issue caused by the upgrade and worth investigating.

My approach is to subtract traffic-rate-POST-upgrade from traffic-rate-PRE-upgrade, assuming offset 30m means traffic rate from 30 mins ago.

```
sum(rate(ifHCInUcastPkts{device="switchX"}[2m])) - sum(rate(ifHCInUcastPkts{device="switchX"}[2m] offset 30m))
```

Option2: I was also looking to see if I could use delta() but that does not seem to work for this case. For example it would be nice to do something like this:

```
delta(sum(rate(ifHCInUcastPkts{device="switchX"}[2m]))[30m])
```

This does not work anyway.

Anyway, looking for help on best way to get this data. Option1 gives me something but not sure I'm really getting what I want. Is that really giving me the rate of traffic now vs the rate of traffic 30 mins ago.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

> Is that really giving me the rate of traffic now vs the rate of traffic 30 mins ago.

Yes, it is. And it seems to give exactly what you described as desired result. Though it might be argued that it is not the best result.

Depending on `scrape_interval` of your Prometheus, and situation in your network it might be wise to consider using something like `increase(..[3m])` instead of `rate`. Because `rate` is per second approximation, and can be victim of sudden changes in counter value, where `increase` over longer range will smooth peaks and canyons.

---

Regarding your second attempt: I believe you should get an error `ranges only allowed for vector selectors`.

This is due to incorrect selector passed to `delta`: since it is not simple vector selector, you need to use subquery syntax. In this case it is enough to simply add `:` to your second range selector.

```
delta(sum(rate(ifHCInUcastPkts{device="switchX"}[2m]))[30m:])
```

Otherwise it is expected to produce same result as first query (plus/minus a tiny approximation error)